# Can I connect my laptop to my non HD TV via a USB to A/V cable to watch movies and YouTube?

Tags: laptop, usb, tv

I have an older non HD TV with A/V jacks and want to use it as a monitor with sound. I want to use a USB to A/V cable to do this. Will that work?

Comment: This only works if the TV supports doing this.  If the hDD was an internal hdd it wouldn't work even if that was the case.

Answer (score 1):

USB is digital and A/V jacks are analog, so I don't believe you will be able to find an A/V cable to do this.   Also, USB is not a video standard, so you would need to find a USB -> AV converter.   While these devices probably exist, you need to be a bit careful as most of the things with USB and A/V jacks will be to capture analog TV, rather then output it.

Despite substantial Googling, I was unable to find a USB device which would do what you want. The closest I could find was a VGA -> RCA converter - which is more expensive then a replacement video card !!!  (I'm not recommending this product, just linking to it for your ref - [http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Resolution-Composite-Converter-VGA2VID/dp/B001NXDQEK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001NXDQEK))